# Google Calendar API returning 403 for some users

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have integrated a small feature that reads the calendar events from each member of my organization's google calendar. It works for the majority but a couple get a 403 returned.

I think this is because they have more than one google account connected to the calendar maybe and I don't have permission to read those other accounts. This is the only reason I can think of. Hope someone can help out here - really stuck for a fix.

I am NOT using 'readonly' scopes. Below is the react function which loads the calendar events for the user.

```
    const loadCalendar = () => {
    window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        console.log("fetching calendar for: ", userEmail);

        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: "xyz",
            clientId: "xyz",
            discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        })

        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().then(() => {
                gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                    'calendarId': 'primary',
                    'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                    'showDeleted': false,
                    'singleEvents': true,
                    'maxResults': 12,
                    'orderBy': 'startTime',
                }).then(({ result }) => {
                    let filteredArr = [];
                    result.items.forEach(item => {
                        let obj = {
                            key: item.id,
                            attendees: item.attendees,
                            start: item.start["date"] ? item.start["date"] : new Date(item.start["dateTime"]).toLocaleString(),
                            summary: item.summary,
                            zoomLink: item.location
                        }
                        filteredArr.push(obj);
                    })
                    setCalendarEvents(filteredArr)
                })
            })
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi there @Tony! To better analyze your situation, please share the code in question. Feel free to obscure any private information on it. Also please clarify if you are using domain wide delegation.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Thanks so much for taking a look. Really has me stumped. Added the code in the edit with secrets removed.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the script I understand that this script works for every user in your organization, except two particular users. In that situation I strongly recommend you to create a [Workspace domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). With that operation you will create an extra account that can access every user data in your organization, so you could access those two users calendars. The only required update is to use the new account credentials in your script. Please check the linked examples and write back if it doesn't work in your scenario.